# NAs in foreign function call trying to open a netcdf file in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I'm using the library ncdf with R version 3.0.2.  I'm trying to open and close some netcdfs over and over again (I can explain why but it isn't needed for this question).

```
sapply(1:14000, function(whatever) {
    print(whatever)
      sapply(prediction.cdfs, function(cdf) {
        print(file.path(cdf.dir, cdf))
        nc = open.ncdf(file.path(cdf.dir, cdf))
        close.ncdf(nc)
      })
})
```

After open and closing over and over again it eventually fails with this error:

```
[1] 3329                                                                                             

[1] "/opt/devel/cdfs/file_one.cdf"

[1] "/opt/devel/cdfs/file_two.cdf"

[1] "/opt/devel/cdfs/file_three.cdf"

[1] "/opt/devel/cdfs/file_four.cdf"

[1] "/opt/devel/cdfs/file_five.cdf"

Error in open.ncdf(file.path(cdf.dir, cdf)) : 
  NAs in foreign function call (arg 1)
```

Anyone know what's going on?  The error seems stochastic in nature.  The time till it barks about the foreign function call is variable.  I'm looking for an explanation or just a work around?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe start by setting `options(error=recover)`, then run the code and poke around when an error throws you into the browser.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Thanks I'll take a look at that.  I'am able to open the netcdf right after throwing the error outside the loop though.  Is that any different than recovery mode?

Comment: I don't know anything about the R packages that deal with netcdf files, so can't give you much informed guidance. That said, I'd use the browser to try to see where those "NAs" in the error message are coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem was from un-closed connections to the same files from a previous step in my analysis.  I'm running this on a Linux system, so I tracked the open file connections as the loop was running using

```
watch ls -l /proc/${PID}/fd
```

The connections opened and closed just fine, but I saw some old connections laying around from my previous analysis.  I closed them and everything run just fine!!!